# How can I test a subscribe?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Anybody helps me? I need to write a unit test for this subscribe.

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notificationService.notifier.do((message) => {
        this.messageNotification = message;
    })
        .switchMap((message) => Observable.timer(2500))
        .subscribe((timer) => this.messageNotification = undefined);
}
```

I managed to get past the 'do', but I can not get past the subscribe.

Here is my test:

```
it('subscribe, do, switchMap', () => {
    const t = 2500;
    expect(() => {
        component.ngOnInit();
        notifyService.notify('error', 'mensagem');
        notifyService.notifier.do((message) => {
            expect(component.messageNotification)
                .toBeDefined();
        })
            .switchMap((message) => Observable.timer(t))
            .subscribe((timer) => {
                component.messageNotification = undefined;
                expect(timer)
                    .toBe(2500);
            });
    }).not
        .toThrow();
});
```